# jquery autocompletion json

Tags: json, jquery-ui

Jquery UI autocompletion does not work with my JSON file. I want to display the values of the name key. Can you help me?

cluster.json :

```
 [
    {
    "name": "A128",
    "ra": "24.97",
    "dec":"12.210"
  },
  {
    "name": "AB 1317",
    "ra": "22.55",
    "dec": "37.124"
  },
  {
    "name": "UBA 133",
    "ra": "35.6",
    "dec": "16.44"
  },
  {
    "name": "UGC 69",
    "ra": "35.6",
    "dec": "16.44"
  }
```

and Jquery in HTML:

```
$('#name').autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url :'cluster.json', 
            dataType : 'json',
            data : request,              
                success: function(data) { 
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return  item.name;
                    }));
                 }
            });     
    }
});
```

When I enter a character there is this error message in the console:
Erreur d’analyse XML : erreur de syntaxe
Emplacement : file:///C:/Users/xxxx/xxxxx/json/cluster.json?term=A
Numéro de ligne 1, Colonne 3 :

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect that this is due an error in your JSON file or that it cannot manage a GET Request.

Comment: It will be better if you attach the code snippet next time (e.g. on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)). You can find more information here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
var myData = [];
$.getJSON("cluster.json", function(data){
  myData = $.map(data, function(v, k){
    return v.name;
  });
});
$('#name').autocomplete({
  source: myData
});
```

If you want to filter the results on your own, you can do that in a number of ways.

This will filter the results based on the input. The final code would look like:

```
var myData = [];
$.getJSON("cluster.json", function(data){
  myData = $.map(data, function(v, k){
    return v.name;
  });
});
$('#name').autocomplete({
  source : function(request, response) {
    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(myData, request.term));
});
```

Both of these examples, I gather all the data first as I assume it's going to be the static data in the JSON file. You could get the data in the source function if you want.

Full Example

```js
var jData = [{
    "name": "A128",
    "ra": "24.97",
    "dec": "12.210"
  },
  {
    "name": "AB 1317",
    "ra": "22.55",
    "dec": "37.124"
  },
  {
    "name": "UBA 133",
    "ra": "35.6",
    "dec": "16.44"
  },
  {
    "name": "UGC 69",
    "ra": "35.6",
    "dec": "16.44"
  }
];
$(function() {
  var myData = $.map(jData, function(v, i) {
    return v.name;
  });
  $('#name').autocomplete({
    source: myData
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="name">Name: </label>
  <input id="name">
</div>
```

Hope that helps.